# MSSQL: How to get multiple values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

For a given "`CustomerId`" I need to get 4 related values from a column ("`CompanySales`") in another table.

I have joined the two tables and, with the query below, manage to get 2 "`CompanySales`" values from the column in the other table.

How do I do this do get 4 values (I need `CompanySales` for "`WeekNumber`" = 1,2,3 and 4)

This is the SQL query I have to secure "`CompanySales`" for "`Weeknumber`" = 1 and 2:

```
Declare @TempTable1 table
(
  CustomerID INT,
  CustomerName Varchar (50),
  CompanySales DEC (8,2),
  WeekNumber INT
)
INSERT INTO @TempTable1 ("CustomerID","CustomerName", "WeekNumber")
SELECT     Customer.CustomerID, Customer.CustomerName, Company.WeekNumber, company.Sales 
FROM         Customer INNER JOIN
                  Company ON Customer.CustomerID = Company.CustomerID;
With tblDifference as
(
Select Row_Number() OVER (Order by WeekNumber) as RowNumber,CustomerID,CustomerName, companysales, WeekNumber from @TempTable1
)
Select Top (50) cur.CustomerID, Cur.CustomerName, Cur.WeekNumber as CurrentWeek, Prv.WeekNumber as PreviousWeek, Cur.CompanySales as CurrentSales,     Prv.CompanySales as  PreviousSales, CAST(((Cur.CompanySales-Prv.CompanySales)/Prv.CompanySales)*100 As Decimal(8,2)) as PercentChange from
tblDifference Cur Left Outer Join tblDifference Prv
On Cur.CustomerID=Prv.CustomerID

Where cur.WeekNumber = 1 AND prv.WeekNumber = 2 
Order BY PercentChange ASC
```

Comment: Just add 2 more AND statements in Where clause?

Comment: What is the `RowNumber` column for? You don't seem to be using it anywhere in your query.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding between there cur.WeekNumber Between 1 and 4?

Comment: Thanks Mandar, I don't fully understand your suggestion. Can you clarify? Maybe provide some suggested syntax to try? Thanks!

Comment: You need data for week numbers 1 to 4 if I understand correctly.So as suggested in other answer, add 2 more wheres, or if your week number is always sequential then try Where cur.WeekNumber between 1 and 4 as your where clause.